# Polymer 1.0 change fields of the Dart objects within themselves to reflect to polymer

Tags: dart, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

Good day. I seem to be having issues being able to have value changes within a Dart Object created by extending JsProxy being reflected to the data binding in a Polymer element. See Below

**person.dart**

```
class Person extends JsProxy {

   @reflectable
   String name;

   Person() {
   name = "temp";
   }

   void changeVar(){
   name = "Matthew";
   }
}
```

**my_element.dart**

```
@PolymerRegister('my-element')
class MyElement extends PolymerElement{

  //Runner Object
  @property Person person = new Person();

  //Constructor
  MyElement.created() : super.created(){ }
```

**my_element.html**

```
<div>
  [[person.name]]
</div>
```

Now I want to be able to call `changeVar()` within its own object and have it reflect on the Polymer element. If I print the variable out after calling `changeVar()` it does show the new value but that value is not reflected within the Polymer element.

Currently the only way I have found to have it change is to use `set('person.name', "matthew")` from within the elements dart file. However I would prefer not to have to implement it there.

Answer (score 2):

Polymer needs to be notified about the change. That's what `set()` or `notifyPath()` or some other Polymer API methods do.

I haven't tried https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer_autonotify but it seems to address your problem.